# Solaris 11 pkg repository update fails

Tags: software-installation, package-management, solaris, gcc

I want to install gcc in my solaris 11 working in virtualbox, I tried

```
    pkg install gcc-45
```

but I am getting :

```
    pkg: 0/1 catalogs successfully updated:

    Unable to contact valid package repository
    Encountered the following error(s):
    Unable to contact any configured publishers.
    This is likely a network configuration problem.
    http protocol error: code: 503 reason: Service Unavailable
    URL: 'http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release'
```

I tried to enter a proxy by entering

```
     export http_proxy=http://184.168.55.226:80
```

But did not work. How can I manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be transient network errors between you and the pkg repo server
which end up with you being unable to contact the repo server.

A better place to ask this particular question would be the Oracle forums
related to Solaris 11. (Try https://community.oracle.com/community/developer/english/server_%26_storage_systems/solaris/solaris_11 to start with).

Does the problem occur if you try again right now? I can get to the search page for the repo server and found http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/p5i/0/developer%2Fgcc-45.p5i very quickly.